# allow space at the beginning + dont allow space between string using regex

Tags: regex

need regex, to allow space at the beginning  but not allow in between of words.

For ex:
"abc abc" - invalid
"   abc" - valid

Answer (score 0):

```
^(([\s])(.[^ ])*)$
```

- Gropu 1 ([\s]) match spaces, tabs line brackes if you want only speces
  just edit: ([ ])
- Gropu 2 (.[^ ])* Mtach any chars without spaces and    line brackes.